# AJAX doesn't work without alert

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to run this code, but without alert in it it doesnt work. Function fotkaID is supposed to pass the id to nastavSession.php where I set a session and then I redirect to ciziProfil.php.  The problem is, when I remove the alert, the session is not set or is set with a wrong value. I think it might be a problem with sync, but I dont know how to fix it.

```
function fotkaID(id) {
  var xhttp;
  alert(id);
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.open("GET", "nastavSession.php?q="+id, true);
  xhttp.send();  
  window.location.href='http://localhost/soc%20sit/ciziProfil.php';
}
```

Comment: *"it doesnt work"* is not a proper problem description. Tell us what it is expected to do and what it is or isn't doing now in a proper explanation. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have set `async` parameter to `true`. So where is your onreadystatechange handler? DO you have something in your code that looks like this: `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) { ... } };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using below code.

```
xhttp.open("GET", "nastavSession.php?q="+id, false);
```